# how to get Umbraco landing page to select a child page as default

Tags: umbraco

I'm working on an umbraco site using the Fanoe starterkit, where I do not want the vistor to land on the landing page, but be redirected to the first grandchild page underneath that.

So that in the example if the visitor clicks Parent or Child1, they would land on Grandchild 1A, if they clicked on child 2 they would land on grandChild 2A, etc. The client does't want to have 'Parent or Child pages' - just grandchild pages... Thoughts?

```
Parent
 - Child 1
 -- Grandchild 1A
 -- Grandchild 1B
 - Child 2
 -- Grandchild 2A
 -- Grandchild 2B
 - Child 3
```

Comment: Sounds odd but one way of doing that is to put a content picker on the document types of the pages that you want to redirect from and name it umbracoInternalRedirectId. Use the picker to chose the page that you want to redirect to... then the magic will happen. This method would leave parent and grandchild pages in the url path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are these pages all the same document type? If your landing pages are a different document type you add something like this to the template:

```
if (Model.Content.DocumentTypeAlias == "LandingPage") {
  Response.Redirect(Model.Content.Child.Url);
}
```

Comment: I did something similar and forgot to add my notes, but your response was  closest to what I did, so I gave you the win. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Add Umbraco Redirect property (UmbracoRedirect) to your home node and select child page. 
Every time you will load home page, it will be redirected to the selected child page.